# No error, but no data written to SQLite DB

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a python list called result that contains 7 items...

```
print result
```

returns

```
[u'2013:11:29', u'17:01:11', u'Apple', u'iPhone 5', -36.57033055555556, 174.68374722222222, '5095c554fef7d990a2c57e0e12b18854']
```

I have this code setting up my DB, and writting the result into the DB

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('geopic.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Results''')
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE Results (Date DATE, Time TIME, Make TEXT, Model TEXT, Latitude FLOAT, Longitude FLOAT, Hash VARCHAR(128))''')
for result in results:
    if result == None:
        continue
    else:
        print result  #this prints as expected
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Results (Date, Time, Make, Model, Latitude, Longitude, Hash) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', result)
```

This runs with no errors, but nothing gets written into the database. I'm stumped as to why!

Comment: Did you try to `commit`?

Answer (score 1):

Append `conn.commit()` to end of your code.

Example:

```
for result in results:
    if result == None:
        continue
    else:
        print result  #this prints as expected
        cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Results (Date, Time, Make, Model, Latitude, Longitude, Hash) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)''', result)
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

OK - Simple Answer - I forgot to use

```
conn.commit()
```

To write the changes to the DB.

DOH!